# Express, NodeJS Authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

Im currently working on a nodejs project and require some authentication. As it stands I just use expresses basicAuth function, however I can't seem to figure out how to do more advanced operations. For example I have two url parameters say bob and steve. If the user navigates to website.com/bob I want it to ask for username:"user" and password:"password". However if the user navigates to website.com/steve I want it to ask for username:"user2" and password:"password123"

Would this be possible using basicAuth and if so how? Or would something like passportjs be able to accomplish this task? I dont need an amazing solution just something to stop people accessing certain areas.

Comment: The question is pretty vague to answer, Please elaborate. If you want know if you should use passport for authentication, I recommend you should.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes I was asking which method would be best for authorising certain pathnames. The only thing with passport is, that in the past having a look at it, it seems rather complex to setup especially since I would have to have 8 different users accessing different areas of the site. Would you know of a good tutorial or maybe a simpler method of doing it?

Comment: You should be doing a single authentication and authorization of accessing. Not doing kind of hybrid. What you are trying to do is the authenticate and authorize together.

Comment: i suggest you to use passportjs module, here the link: http://passportjs.org/
Then, perform a basic local strategy as shown in the website examples.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is probably access control and I suggest you use a access control list module which will allow you to implement policies as to which users/groups have access to which resources within your application.

This way, even if a user provides their username/password pair, they will not be allowed to access that resource based on the policy which is a better option application design wise.

For a start:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/acl

Comment: Hi, that website is rather vague with information on how to implement it. Would you know how I would be able to use it in my system to protect different pathnames with different users?